# How to make sense of results from the IRS W-4 withholding calculator?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, withholding, form-w-4

After entering all my data into the calculator, attempting to get a handle on how much we are going to owe next year, I received this summary, which makes no sense at all:
[image]

If $947 will be due when I file my taxes, why do I need to withhold an additional $3,015? It states that my balance or refund will be, if I take that action, less than $25. How does that make any sense? Thanks.

Comment: What number of allowances do you claim now?

Comment: Do you already have additional withholding in your W4?  It does not say you have to increase your additional withholding *by* 3015, it says you have to set it *to* 3015.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer We claim zero allowances.

Comment: @jjanes We do not have any additional withholding beyond what is taken out "normally" with zero allowances claimed. For your second point, I'm not sure what the difference is there. My "current withholding arrangement" is simply whats taken out with zero allowances. It states that if I continue my "current withholding arrangement" I will owe $942 and suggests a remedy of changing my withholding arrangement by increasing it $3015 above simple claiming zero allowances. I don't understand the discrepancy between $942 short and $3015 additional to balance it. Thanks for looking, it's appreciated.

Comment: If you look at the `withheld to date`, the `withheld from last check`, and the `projected additional withholding`, it seems that their calculator thinks your paychecks have been once per week so far this year, but will be once per two weeks for the rest of the year.  I don't know if this reflects something you have told them, or if it reflects an error in their computations; but this is where I would start investigating.